# Is It good practice to perform an operation in parts?

Tags: node.js, performance, file, websocket, server

I am really stuck on a point while doing a search in 100 files of at least 20 MB each. Why is my request for a search taking too much time?

Is it ok to perform that search in parts? Let's suppose I can send 100 requests and in each request can perform the search in 1 file; so this search can be performed simultaneously. And also explain either this can affect server performance while sending 100 requests parallel.

i am sending emit request to socket.io to the node.js server.

Comment: I don't see how this would reduce the work or speedup anything. It only moves the complexity of merging search results to the client.

Comment: That’s probably not going to speed anything up. If disk read is your bottleneck and you only have one disk, reads aren’t going to happen in parallel; if you’re CPU-bound in JavaScript and still only running one Node process, you’ll remain that way, because Node only runs a single thread of JavaScript. (If neither of these is the case, any parallelism is still better done by the server and not at the request level.) What kind of search do you need to perform? There is probably a better way to store your data to make it searchable.

Comment: If your data can be indexed in any way, consider using a proper database.